# jquery image slider not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, slider

I have used an image slider (Lean Slider) on my website and it works great in IE9+, FF, Chrome, but for some reason doesn't work in IE8.

I've been trying to solve this for days and am really stuck! Would be extremely grateful for any help!

Can anyone work this out and why its not working in IE8?

HTML CODE :

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.berkshire.co.za/js/lean-slider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.berkshire.co.za/css/lean-slider.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.berkshire.co.za/sample-styles.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Bershire & Black | Finest custom suits and shirts |</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 

</head>

<body ">

  <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="http://www.berkshire.co.za/images/slider/slider1.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide2">
                <img src="http://www.berkshire.co.za/images/slider/slider2.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide3">
                <img src="http://www.berkshire.co.za/images/slider/slider3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide4">
                <img src="http://www.berkshire.co.za/images/slider/slider4.jpg" alt="" / >
            </div>
            <div class="slide5">
                <img src="http://www.berkshire.co.za/images/slider/slider5.jpg" alt="" / >
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div id="slider-direction-nav"></div>
        <div id="slider-control-nav"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var slider = $('#slider').leanSlider({
            directionNav: '#slider-direction-nav',
            controlNav: '#slider-control-nav'
        });
    });
    </script>


  </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE :

```
/*
 * Lean Slider v1.0
 * http://dev7studios.com/lean-slider
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

.lean-slider { 
    position: relative; 
    *zoom: 1;
}
.lean-slider:before,
.lean-slider:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.lean-slider:after {
    clear: both;
}

.lean-slider-slide { 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    display: none; 
}
.lean-slider-slide.current { display: block; }

/*
 * Lean Slider Sample Styles
 * http://dev7studios.com/lean-slider
 */

.slider-wrapper { 
    position: relative; 
    background: #fff url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.lean-slider { overflow: hidden; }
.lean-slider-slide {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
}
.lean-slider-slide.current { opacity: 1; }
.lean-slider-slide img { 
    display: block;
    width: 100%; 
}

#slider-direction-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 47%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.slider-wrapper:hover #slider-direction-nav { opacity: 1; }
#slider-direction-nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 37px;
    background: url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#slider-direction-nav .lean-slider-next {
    float: right;
    background-position: 100% ;
}

#slider-control-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.slider-wrapper:hover #slider-control-nav { opacity: 1; }
#slider-control-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
#slider-control-nav a.active { background-position: 100% 0; }

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {

    #slider-direction-nav,
    #slider-control-nav { opacity: 1; }

}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

    #slider-direction-nav,
    #slider-control-nav { opacity: 1; }

}
```

JS CODE

```
/*
 * Lean Slider v1.0
 * http://dev7studios.com/lean-slider
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

;(function($) {

    $.fn.leanSlider = function(options) {

        // Defaults
        var defaults = {
            pauseTime: 4000,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            startSlide: 0,
            directionNav: '',
            directionNavPrevBuilder: '',
            directionNavNextBuilder: '',
            controlNav: '',
            controlNavBuilder: '',
            prevText: 'Prev',
            nextText: 'Next',
            beforeChange: function(){},
            afterChange: function(){},
            afterLoad: function(){}
        };

        // Set up plugin vars
        var plugin = this,
            settings = {},
            slider = $(this),
            slides = slider.children(),
            currentSlide = 0,
            timer = 0;

        var init = function() {
            // Set up settings
            settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            // Add inital classes
            slider.addClass('lean-slider');
            slides.addClass('lean-slider-slide');

            currentSlide = settings.startSlide;
            if(settings.startSlide < 0 || settings.startSlide >= slides.length) currentSlide = 0;
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('current');

            // Set up directionNav
            if(settings.directionNav && $(settings.directionNav).length){
                var prevNav = $('<a href="#" class="lean-slider-prev">'+ settings.prevText +'</a>'),
                    nextNav = $('<a href="#" class="lean-slider-next">'+ settings.nextText +'</a>');
                if(settings.directionNavPrevBuilder) prevNav = $(settings.directionNavPrevBuilder.call(this, settings.prevText));
                if(settings.directionNavNextBuilder) nextNav = $(settings.directionNavNextBuilder.call(this, settings.nextText));

                prevNav.on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    plugin.prev();
                });
                nextNav.on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    plugin.next();
                });

                $(settings.directionNav).append(prevNav);
                $(settings.directionNav).append(nextNav);
            }

            // Set up controlNav
            if(settings.controlNav && $(settings.controlNav).length){
                slides.each(function(i){
                    var controlNav = $('<a href="#" class="lean-slider-control-nav">'+ (i + 1) +'</a>');
                    if(settings.controlNavBuilder) controlNav = $(settings.controlNavBuilder.call(this, i, $(slides[i])));

                    controlNav.on('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        plugin.show(i);
                    });

                    $(settings.controlNav).append(controlNav);
                });
            }

            // Set up pauseOnHover
            if(settings.pauseOnHover && settings.pauseTime && settings.pauseTime > 0){
                slider.hover(
                    function () {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    },
                    function () {
                        doTimer();
                    }
                );
            }

            // Initial processing
            updateControlNav();
            doTimer();

            // Trigger the afterLoad callback
            settings.afterLoad.call(this);

            return plugin;
        };

        // Process timer
        var doTimer = function(){
            if(settings.pauseTime && settings.pauseTime > 0){
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){ plugin.next(); }, settings.pauseTime);
            }
        };

        // Update controlNav
        var updateControlNav = function(){
            if(settings.controlNav){
                $('.lean-slider-control-nav', settings.controlNav).removeClass('active');
                $($('.lean-slider-control-nav', settings.controlNav).get(currentSlide)).addClass('active');
            }  
        };

        // Prev
        plugin.prev = function(){
            // Trigger the beforeChange callback
            settings.beforeChange.call(this, currentSlide);

            currentSlide--;
            if(currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
            slides.removeClass('current');
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('current');
            updateControlNav();
            doTimer();

            // Trigger the afterChange callback
            settings.afterChange.call(this, currentSlide);
        };

        // Next
        plugin.next = function(){
            // Trigger the beforeChange callback
            settings.beforeChange.call(this, currentSlide);

            currentSlide++;
            if(currentSlide >= slides.length) currentSlide = 0;
            slides.removeClass('current');
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('current');
            updateControlNav();
            doTimer();

            // Trigger the afterChange callback
            settings.afterChange.call(this, currentSlide);
        };

        // Show
        plugin.show = function(index){
            // Trigger the beforeChange callback
            settings.beforeChange.call(this, currentSlide);

            currentSlide = index;
            if(currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
            if(currentSlide >= slides.length) currentSlide = 0;
            slides.removeClass('current');
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('current');
            updateControlNav();
            doTimer();

            // Trigger the afterChange callback
            settings.afterChange.call(this, currentSlide);
        };

        // Call constructor
        return init();
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: jsfiddle would make it easier to debug

Comment: IE8 doesn't suppor CSS3 and your slider seems to make use of it.

Comment: "I've been trying to solve this for days and am really stuck!" In these days, you didn't have check DOC & support?

Answer (score 6):

As detailed in [its website](http://dev7studios.com/lean-slider/):

> **Requirements**
>
> Works in all major browsers including IE9+. Requires jQuery v1.8.

Answer (score 2):

Lean Slider only supports Internet 9 and higher according to their website:

> Requirements:
>
> Works in all major browsers including **IE9+**. Requires jQuery v1.8.

Comment: I literally posted this a few seconds after @alvaro, this was not intentional copying. There's no need to downvote

Comment: Thanks guys. Can anyone recommend an alternative image slider which is more browser friendly? Including IE8?

Comment: I personally wouldn't bother. The number of people who use IE8 are too low to go out of your way to cater to them IMO

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems too to work with Lean Slider in Internet Explorer 8. I fixed this by adding a comment in file "sample-styles.css", see the line "display: block;" and now the controlNav works and navBar too, links works and slide fine in all others browsers.

```
.lean-slider-slide {
  /*display: block;*/
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
}
```